# What is happening between `Is collating: yes` and ` Local node identity is:...` or why is it taking so long time to restart syncing of a crashed node?

Tags: parachain, sync, client

I'm trying to sync a parachain node from scratch with a client upgraded to `polkadot0.9.37`

I have experienced crashes and restarts after a few hours and with every subsequent restart it seems to take longer to restart the node.

In this log I found a gap for several hours

```
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Nodle Parachain Collator    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 2.0.26-5632a16685e    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Nodle <support@nodle.com>:Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2020-2023    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Nodle Parachain    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: fretful-rings-3704    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at .testdrivedata-master/chains/para_eden/db/full    
2023-03-02 10:53:18.588  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: nodle-para-17 (nodle-para-0.tx6.au1)    
2023-03-02 10:53:24.642  INFO main nodle_parachain::command: Parachain id: Id(2026)    
2023-03-02 10:53:24.642  INFO main nodle_parachain::command: Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPa9Z5gxN6u3dL6bydrbCkwpiaWuvanrZKegBPQUXMk    
2023-03-02 10:53:24.642  INFO main nodle_parachain::command: Parachain genesis state: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041acf2b680686c9cb62433905459d97c5e820e1674c08e7ad66d2a307305634003170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400    
2023-03-02 10:53:24.642  INFO main nodle_parachain::command: Is collating: yes    
2023-03-02 14:59:18.987  INFO main sub-libp2p: [Relaychain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWHxy6acp5PmoatkbudPqGG9PVQdxKbvkiCgaPJTtdR1MW    
2023-03-02 14:59:18.991  WARN main sub-libp2p: [Relaychain] Can't listen on /ip6/::/tcp/30334/ws because: Other(Custom { kind: Other, error: Other(A(A(A(A(Transport(A(Transport(Os { code: 98, kind: AddrInUse, message: "Address already in use" })))))))) })    
2023-03-02 14:59:18.991  WARN main sub-libp2p: [Relaychain] Can't listen on /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30334/ws because: Other(Custom { kind: Other, error: Other(A(A(A(A(Transport(A(Transport(Os { code: 98, kind: AddrInUse, message: "Address already in use" })))))))) })    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Operating system: linux    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU architecture: x86_64    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Target environment: gnu    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700 @ 2.50GHz    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU cores: 8    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Memory: 63923MB    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Kernel: 5.14.0-1057-oem    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Linux distribution: Linux Mint 20.2    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Virtual machine: no    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.591  INFO main sc_service::builder: [Relaychain]  Highest known block at #9710531    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.595  INFO main sc_rpc_server: [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:42981, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_rpc_server: [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:40447, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU score: 988.39 MiBs    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Memory score: 11.40 GiBs    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 53.57 MiBs    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 29.16 MiBs
```

What is it doing between `10:53:24.642`  and `14:59:18.987` ? In the earliest logs I captured this gap was only a few seconds.

Comment: Please post the cli flags you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a pretty old HHD.

It takes a long time to load the data.

```
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 53.57 MiBs    
2023-03-02 14:59:20.596  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 29.16 MiBs
```

I'm using SSD. And It still takes a few seconds on my side.

```
2023-03-02 14:56:14 [Relaychain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 9.70 GiBs    
2023-03-02 14:56:14 [Relaychain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 3.49 GiBs
```

So, I think the only option is upgrading your hardware.

Comment: There are some other work going on on this computer. And I see variations from 1G down to 20 M. But the question is what is happening when there are no prints for several hours.

Comment: AFAIK, it was loading the latest state from the DB. You can set `RUST_LOG=db`.

Comment: No logs from `RUST_LOG`=db in this section